# reordering dendrograms on a clustergram in matlab

Tags: matlab, fonts, heatmap, dendrogram

I have generated a clustergram based on a dataset of normalized values, but I want to attempt to reorder the samples along the y-axis.  I haven't come across much information on how to go about doing that after googling.  Below is my code thus far:  Any help would be appreciated.

```
    [num, txt]= xlsread('S:\Breast\Breast Stats no post XRT.xls', 'Breast heat');
    PID= txt(2:93,1);
    varname = txt(1,2:23);
    cgram = clustergram(num(1:92,:));
    set(cgram,'Standardize',3,'Cluster',3, 'RowLabels',PID(:,:), 'ColumnLabels',                                       varname(:,:),...
    'Linkage','ward','Dendrogram',3,'ColumnPdist', 'euclidean', 'RowPdist', 'euclidean', 'OptimalLeafOrder', 'true',...
 'SymmetricRange', 'false');
```

Also, does anyone know how to set the font size for the labels for ONE particular axis only?

Answer (score 0):

About the main problem:

Suppose you put your data in nx2 a matrix `A` then you can sort it according to a column like this:

```
[Y,I]=sort(A(:,2)); % Sort by column 2 of the matrix
B=A(I,:); %use the indices from sort() to sort all rows of A.
```

Answer (score 0):

To reorder the elements in the clustergram, you can set the `OptimalLeafOrder` property of the clustergram.

To set the font size for the labels, you can use the `addXLabel` or `addYLabel` commands, and then directly set the `FontSize` property of the text object returned.

See `doc clustergram` and `doc addXLabel` for more information and examples.

Comment: Hi,  I got:
    ??? Undefined function or method 'addYLabel' for input arguments of type 'clustergram'.

Comment: You should be able to type `h = addYLabel(cgram, 'mylabel')` and then, for example, `set(h, 'FontSize', 14)`. Are you doing that and getting an error?

Comment: Hi Sam, Yes, I am still getting an error.  h = addYLabel(cgram, 'RowLabels')

Comment: Weird, I'm not sure why that might be. I'll try to look into it and comment again - my apologies if I take a little time to do that.